# Unable to Retrieve the value from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve values from my firebase database.

It is displaying the values in onDataChange() function but unable to display the values out of it .

Code:

```
public Records readtraditional(String email)
{
    final Records record = new Records();
    final String[] name = new String[1];

    myRef.child(email).child("name").addValueEventListener(new 
    ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() ;
        //Printing value of name here
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    Log.i("name in ","H"+name[0]);
    //Unable to print value of name here
    record.setName(name[0]);
    return record;
}
```

Comment: Response from Firebase is asynchronous. When you try to print values outside OnDataChange probably you haven't got any response from server and your name array is still empty and onDataChange is being called later

Comment: @matip , I know this but what is the solution.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment call to Firebase is asynchronous. If you want your method to return `Records` object you should use callback:

```
public void readtraditional(String email, MyCallback callback)
{
    final Records record = new Records();
    final String[] name = new String[1];

    myRef.child(email).child("name").addValueEventListener(new 
    ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() ;                
            record.setName(name[0]);
            callback.onSuccess(record)
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });   

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MyCallback{
           void onSuccess(Records record)
}
```

And you can call this method like this:

```
readtraditional(mystring,new MyCallback{
        @Override
        void onSuccess(Records record){
            //do whatever you want
        }
});
```